# Passing HTML input value as a JavaScript Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass user-inputted values as a parameter to a JavaScript function. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<h1>Adding 'a' and 'b'</h1>
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" name="b" id="a"><br>
  <button onclick="add(a,b)">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  function add(a,b) {
    var sum = a + b;
    alert(sum);
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One way is by using `document.getElementByID`, as below -

```html
<body>
  <h1>Adding 'a' and 'b'</h1>

  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br> b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
  <button onclick="add(document.getElementById('a').value,document.getElementById('b').value)">Add</button>

  <script>
    function add(a, b) {
      var sum = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
      alert(sum);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay, your solution is somewhat working. However, it is concatenating it as if a and b were strings. So sum is 12 instead of 3 where a=1 and b=2.

Comment: `var sum = Number(a) + Number(b);`

Answer (score 14):

Firstly an elements ID should always be unique. If your element IDs aren't unique then you would always get conflicting results. Imagine in your case using two different elements with the same ID.

```
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
</form>

<script>
  function add() {
    var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('b').value;

    var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    alert(sum);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there no way to actually pass these items as a parameter though?

Answer (score 9):

## 1 IDs are meant to be unique

## 2 You dont need to pass any argument as you can call them in your javascript

```
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  function add() {
    var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var sum = a + b;
    alert(sum);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   <form action="" onsubmit="additon()" name="form1" id="form1">
      a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
      b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
   </form>
  <script>
      function additon() 
      {
           var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
           var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
           var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
           return sum;
      }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values with use of `ID`. But `ID` should be Unique.

```
<body>
<h1>Adding 'a' and 'b'</h1>
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  function add() {
    a = $('#a').val();
    b = $('#b').val();
    var sum = a + b;
    alert(sum);
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you use jquery?
if then:

```
$('#xx').val();
```

or use original javascript(DOM)

```
document.getElementById('xx').value
```

or

```
xxxform.xx.value;
```

if you want to learn more, w3chool can help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will work,

```
<body>
<h1>Adding 'a' and 'b'</h1>
<form>
  a: <input type="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" name="b" id="a"><br>
  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  function add() {
    var m = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var n = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var sum = m + n;
    alert(sum);
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like how most answers here don't know that javascript accepts every input as string unless we use parseInt.
Yes, you can pass parameters in that way.
Just a little modification

```
Var sum = parseFloat(a)+parseFloat (b);
```

Try it (⁠｡⁠•̀⁠ᴗ⁠-⁠)⁠✧