# Pass form inputs to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, forms

### TL;DR: Is there a way to pass what a HTML form submits as an object to a JavaScript function?

In a form like this one:

```
<form action="javascript:myFunction(this);" name="myForm">
<label>First: <input type="text" name="first"></label>
<label>Second: <input type="text" name="second"></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit this to Javascript!">
</form>
```

I want to pass the values of the form's inputs to a JavaScript function `myFunction`, instead of sending them to some other page with `action` (as in this line here: `action="sendToPHPPage.php"`).

So far, my best attempt was to get all elements from the form, like this:

```
function myFunction(formThis) {
  let form = document.getElementsByName('myForm')[0];
  inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (let x of inputs) //do something with x.value

  console.log(formThis);
}
```

What I wanted, though, was that the `this` in `myFunction(this)` would allow me directly work on the inputs of the form. So instead of using `document.getElementsByName('myForm')` I could simply work on the `this` argument. But `console.log(thisForm)` tells me that `formThis === window`. That is, `this` gets me the window object.

*Question*: How can I make the `this` be binded to the form -- that is, how can I make the `this` argument represent the form or become an object that has as keys each one of the inputs? Is this possible without using `document.get... || document.querySelector...`?

---

Related SO questions: [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript) , [Passing HTML input value as a JavaScript Function Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397743/passing-html-input-value-as-a-javascript-function-parameter)

Comment: Have you tried adding an event listener to the form on `submit` event? If so you can get access to the form using the `event.currentTarget` inside the callback where `event` is the passed argument to the callback

Comment: Good call! That's what I'm thinking now, adding an `onlick` attribute to submit, oy maybe changing it to a `type="button"` like  here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Language-Basics/PassingtheFormObjectasaParameter.htm . I'm gonna try that now

Comment: I mentioned `submit` event because the form can be submitted in multiple ways via mouse or keyboard, in order to not trying to catch different cases you can use `submit` event which will get do this unnecessary work for you. Also if you go with `click` listener the `event.currentTarget` will be the button which seem like not what you want from the description

Comment: @AntK strange... I took out the `action` attribute from form (that is, now form is just `<form name="myForm">`) and changed the type of the submit button to `type="button"` and then added `onclick="myFunction(this.form)"` I get: `TypeError: myFunction is not a function`. But I can call myFunction and it is clearly a function. What's wrong here?

Comment: @AntK I still don't know why using onclick I got an error, but addEventListener worked flawlessly as you guessed. Do you want to write that as an answer so I can pick it? I'd still like to know, though, if it's possible to "submit" the form as an object to JavaScript, but I don't think there's a ready made function for that

Comment: Sure, no problem, my guess is that you have to pass a function there, but you called a function with `this` which in return does not return a function. I could be wrong here though

Comment: @AntK I tried removing the `this` argument (`onclick="myFunction();"`), but I get the same `TypeError`. I need to use `addEventListener` for it to work. Really strange

Comment: I am not too sure, sorry. Adding event listeners via `addEventListener` gives you a passed event as well as an option to remove the event listener when needed, while inlining these makes it not as streamlined, however this can be my personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to bind an event listener to the form with a callback that you want to be called when a form is submitted, your code will look something like this

```
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from reloading the page
  const form = event.currentTarget;
  // your logic goes here
}

document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', myFunction);
```

Please note I've added an id `my-form` to the form to make it easier to select on the page.

Comment: I'd only suggest one more thing: to put the addEventListener statement after the window is loaded. Like: `window.onload = () => {document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', myFunction);};`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="contact_form" onsubmit="return sendForm()">
```

---

```
const sendForm = () => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event.target.elements[***])
    }
```