# Fibonacci numbers in Html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is Fibonacci numbers codes in HTML and it is supposed to print out Fibonacci numbers after taking the users input which can be any number

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          function fib(number) {

    var loop = [0, 1];

    for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        loop[i] = loop[i-1]+ loop[i-2];


    return loop[number-1];
    }

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML
    }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type text="text" id="txtloop" />
        <input type="button" id="btnEnter" value="Enter" onclick="fib(txtloop.value)" />

        <p id="output"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You missed the part that says what your problem is.

Comment: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML` is there all by itself....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fibonacci Sequence is the series of numbers: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, . . . Each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two.

```html
<html>
<body>

 <input type text="text" id="txtloop" />
        <input type="button" id="btnEnter" value="Enter" onclick="fibonacci_series(txtloop.value)" />

        <p id="output"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fibonacci_series = function (n) 
{
  if (n==1) 
  {
var loop = [0, 1];
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = loop;
  return loop;
  } 
  else 
  {
    var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =s;
    return s;
  }
   
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Access DOM elements with [HTML DOM querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
function fib() {
let loop = [0, 1];
let number=document.getElementById('txtloop').value;
for (let i = 2; i < number; i++)
 loop[i] = loop[i-1]+ loop[i-2];
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=loop[number-1];
}
```

```html
<input type text="text" id="txtloop" />
<button onclick="fib()">Enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Read more:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp
- [Passing HTML input value as a JavaScript Function Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397743/passing-html-input-value-as-a-javascript-function-parameter)