# Is there a way to get Material-UI's textfield to return a number instead of a string when used with type="number"?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, textfield, react-hook-form

I am using Material-UI's `TextField` in conjunction with `react-hook-form` to watch inputs.
I have noticed that regardless of the type of the input, a string is returned.
This clashes with the types I use in the codebase.

I have read about different ways to handle this issue on `react-hook-form`'s side, with transforming the returned data but I couldn't find anything about making TextField return a different type depending on how it's used.
I'm especially surprised because as far as I understand, `valueAsNumber` exists natively on HTML inputs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get MUI's `<TextField>` to innately return a number type. This is because `<TextField>` is built off of the HTML `<input>` element, which is, by nature, a *text* field.

If you're able to use the `<TextField>` component in a controlled state, you can easily convert the returned type with the onChange handler using `valueAsNumber`:

```
<TextField
    id="outlined-controlled"
    label="Number Field"
    value={numValue}
    type="number"
    onChange={(event) => {
        setNumValue(event.target.valueAsNumber);
    }}
/>
```

Of course you can always get specific with the number type using methods like `parseInt(event.target.value)` or `parseFloat(event.target.value)`. There are a number of conversion techniques available, laid out nicely in this article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-javascript/.

If you're constrained to using `<TextField>` in an uncontrolled form-submission context, there are options available laid out in: [Passing HTML input value as a JavaScript Function Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397743/passing-html-input-value-as-a-javascript-function-parameter).